# Failed to initialized NVIDIA card

Tags: nvidia

Here is the log from `dmesg`:

```
[    2.172069] NVRM: Can't find an IRQ for your NVIDIA card!
[    2.172070] NVRM: Please check your BIOS settings.
[    2.172070] NVRM: [Plug & Play OS] should be set to NO
[    2.172071] NVRM: [Assign IRQ to VGA] should be set to YES 
[    2.172072] nvidia: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -1
[    2.172080] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 242
[    2.172086] NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine failed for 1 device(s).
[    2.172087] NVRM: None of the NVIDIA graphics adapters were initialized!
[    2.172088] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 242
```

I've disabled secure boot in bios and still got the same error. Any suggestions?

- Nvidia GTX1050
- Ubuntu 17.04
- Kernel: 4.12.0-13-generic

Comment: have u tried empty some irq slots for NVidia card from BIOS settings ? say for example if you are not using com ports 1-2 , disable them, any onboard VGA card or any usb slot etc.

Comment: I didn't see anything related to IRQ com ports. Do you know how to access that? My laptop is a Dell XPS15 9560.

Comment: the BIOS can be accessed by pressing ESC, Del or F2 when you first power on the computer. first check  **cat  /proc/irqs** , it will list the irqs in use

Comment: I've already looked into BIOS, there is nothing related to IRQ there. On my system there is no /proc/irqs. There is a directory /proc/irq though.

Answer (score 2):

acpi=force is a boot parameter which states ::

Activates the ACPI system even if your computer BIOS is prior to 2000. This parameter overwrites acpi=off and can also be used with current hardware if the ACPI support is not activated despite apm=off.

It overrides the acpi=off and also put the irq in polling mode which eventually **reduces driver initialization failures** due to shared interrupts.

Once you make any changes to  /etc/default/grub you have to run update-grub for it to be effective by next boot up.

Comment: so acpi has become obsolete? what is the upcoming replacement?

Answer (score 1):

Tried to fix this by setting

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
```

in `/etc/default/grub`.

Worked for once, then the same problem again.

---

### Update

`sudo update-grub` seems to solve the problem. Although I don't quite understand why `acpi=force` has anything to do with the loading of a graphic card. If anyone has more info, please post an answer. Thanks!

Comment: run update-grub after this